# How to revert code to state of last deployment in Apps Script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an Apps Script project I edit relatively infrequently, and use the UI to do so. In it, I would like to revert any changes made back to the most recent deployment, because I was working on something and don't recall what I had changed (and is it now irrelevant). A branch, if there were such a thing in the Apps Script UI, would solve this workflow.

I can see my previous deployments, but cannot find a way to view the current state of the code at that point, or revert "Head" back to it. Can anyone share a recommendation?

Comment: If you want to achieve your goal by only UI of the script editor, unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, after the new IDE has been released, this cannot be achieved. But, I believe that this will be resolved in the future update. So, as the current workaround, how about using Google Apps Script API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest) I think that when Google Apps Script API is used, your goal can be achieved. How about this workaround? If this was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike appreciate that option, it's a fine workaround since it gets the job done but it is truly disheartening working with anything Google owns these days. These gotchas are hardly few and far between, whether Apps Script or nearly anything else. No fault of yours just venting -- very much appreciate the solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your goal has been able to be achieved with the old IDE. But, after the new IDE was released, unfortunately, it seems that your goal cannot be directly achieved. But, I believe that this will be implemented in the future update. By the way, if you want a sample script using my proposed workaround, feel free to tell me.

Comment: All set, I was able to get what I needed via the API and Postman.